# web.config: exclude wordpress folder from redirect rule

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web-config

I have an ASP website which forces (www) in urls using *web.config* rules. This website has a subfolder containing Wrodpress(php) which tries to remove (www) so its rules conflicts with the main website.

I don't know if the Wordpress is using a plugin or *.htaccess* to remove www so I don't want to modify the wordpress settings but to exclude the wordpress folder from top level **web.config** redirect rules. This is what I have tried so far but not working:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com/wrodpress" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com/wrodpress" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining complex rules, stop processing on special folder before other rules:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ignore blog" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^wrodpress/" />
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```